# Port forwarding with iptables not working anymore

Tags: ssh, iptables, port-forwarding

I installed SSH honeypot cowrie and configured real ssh to use a different port. The honeypot is supposed to use a port *n*. Iptables is configured to route traffic from  port `22` to port `%PORT`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port %PORT
```

Cowrie is just running fine, this works:

```
ssh root@localhost -p %PORT
```

What's not working is this:

```
ssh root@localhost
```

Same for remote connections (except, port %PORT is not working, because it's not opened.

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Real SSH itself is working pretty fine on it's secret port somewhere.

Those are the nat-rules from iptables:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh redir ports %PORT

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Those are the global rules from iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    f2b-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports pop3,imap2
2    f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
[... removed some mappings not related to this toppics (http-specific, some mail-ports)]
15   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:%REAL_SSH_PORT ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-dovecot-pop3imap (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     all  --  XXXXXXX  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2    REJECT     all  --  XXXXXXX  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
3    REJECT     all  --  XXXXXXX  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
4    REJECT     all  --  XXXXXXX       anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Some side-notes:

1. Choosing a different source port, like 99, will also not work
2. Using a local port forwarding rule like this works pretty fine when connecting from local machine

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-port %PORT
   ```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Connections from the local system don't traverse the PREROUTING table. I believe for those connections you need to use the OUTPUT chain. You also need to allow %PORT in the INPUT table.

Comment: open %PORT in INPUT table... That's it. Spend hours searching. Thanks a lot. You want to post answer or should I answer my question myself?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wurtel - PREROUTING does *not* imply opening a port. I also had to open the SSH-honeypots port like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport %PORT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```